# How to hide a shell script running in the background from ps -ef

Tags: bash, shell, process, hide

I am trying to hide a shell script that runs in the background from `ps -ef`, `ps -aux` etc.

Currently when I type `ps -ef`, I see:

```
/bin/bash ./script_name.sh
```

I need to hide only that specific script.
I tried to alias the `bashrc` file to `grep -v` the script name but it didn't work.

Comment: My, this is suspicious

Comment: i swear it isn't for malicious meanings

Comment: what *is* it for then?

Comment: prank my roommate... its only for fun

Comment: if that's only to prank someone you could put a changed `ps` on your `PATH` which prints a dummy output, or better sill  does not display what you want to hide

Comment: Care to show an example? I know the SED command that removes the line I want, but I don't know how to change the PATH

Comment: I've added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is only to prank your roommate here it goes:

Backup you `ps` binary:

```
mv /bin/ps /bin/ps.original
```

Create a impostor `ps`:

```
cat > /bin/ps
#! /bin/bash

hide="thunderbird"
ps.original $@ | grep -v "$hide"
```

Don't forget to make it executable:

```
chmod +x /bin/ps
```

The above example I am hiding thunderbird but could be anything really.

Comment: when you said backup, didn't you mean to copy it? instead of renaming it?

Comment: no, It's really moving it. but considering that you are going to overwrite it anyway with `cat` does not really matter.

Comment: first of all, it worked, thank you!
now when i type ps it doesnt show it but it does show:
/bin/bash /bin/ps -ef
is this normal?

Comment: you can hide whatever you want now, just add another `grep -v`